# cakePHP - Join with conditional virtual field

Tags: mysql, cakephp, join

Is there a way I can generate this query with cakePHP :

```
SELECT pl.zban_player_id 'Player', pl.display_info 'GUID', pl.source_group 'Source',     
IF(pv.variable_value is not null, 1,0) as  SyncProcessed
FROM banner_key_current bkc
INNER JOIN banner_key_current_ext bkce ON bkc.banner_key_id = bkce.banner_key_id
INNER JOIN operations op ON op.operation_id = bkc.operation_id
INNER JOIN players pl ON pl.zban_player_id = bkce.identifier
INNER JOIN playermap_now pmn ON pmn.zban_player_id = pl.zban_player_id
LEFT JOIN player_variables pv ON (pv.zban_player_id = pl.zban_player_id AND pv.variable_name = 'player_sync_processed')
WHERE bkc.date BETWEEN '2014-05-01' AND '2014-11-13'
AND op.category = 117
AND pmn.user_id IN (1)
Group By bkce.identifier
```

What I want to return is the alias field `SyncProcessed` based on the condition

I'v tried using joins but couldn't get this result

Comment: The short answer is Yes.  You can always use the [query method](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-query). FYI: Your query may work but it is a poor practice to implement `GROUP BY` without any aggregate functions and also a poor practice to not `GROUP BY` all non-aggregate columns used in the `SELECT`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. Yes I'm sure the query is 0 percent optimised. The reason for this is because the query might get complicated even, especially when using sub-queries.. I did not include such complex queries because. What I really intended to ask was whether or not this can be done using cake's traditional way, using joins array etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom query by using this :

```
$this->YourModel->query('your query here')
```